# Get Unicode character from String representing Unicode code point in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I am trying to convert the string, representing a Unicode code point, Ex. `'03A9'`, into the corresponding unicode character, Ex. Ω (Greek Omega, U+03A9). The code point is meant to be able to vary so I cannot hard code the value.  Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:-

```
>> chr(int("03A9",  base=16))
```